# How to run a seeder file already runned file in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

i am using Laravel seeder for inserting some data , it's already seeded without any errors now i added some extra data in the same file how can i run that same seeder file again...?

```
file_name is `2022_05_13_110617_dummyDataSeeder.php`

command i ran :- `php artisan db:seed`
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/seeding#running-seeders

Comment: Did you create seeder or migration? Your filename looks like a migration. To rerun the migration you should rollback using `php artisan migrate:rollback` and the migrate again.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify class to run while db:seed

Example command

```
php artisan db:seed --class=ClassNameHere
```

Docs Link: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/seeding#running-seeders

Comment: it's throwing error class option does not exist

Comment: What is your seeder class name ?  you need to place that name in the command. Example: `php artisan db:seed --class=UserSeeder`  make sure UserSeeder.php exists in folder database/seeders

Comment: in my case `data\Seeders\all` because i am using apiato farmework (`php artisan apiato:generate:seeder  `)

Comment: class name is Users2Seeder and file name is 2022_05_13_110617_user2Seeder.php

Comment: `2022_05_13_110617_user2Seeder.php` this is the migration format, where is this file placed ?

Comment: under Data\Seeders\all

Answer (score 1):

If you are in development and don't mind the data being deleted first (***NOTE DATA WILL BE LOST***) then run:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Make sure you have backups.